# Cypress, got wrong result when use "Cypress.Commands.add" to defined a new command

Tags: javascript, cypress

I defined a new command in "commands.js"

```
Cypress.Commands.add('subValues', (a, b) => { return a - b });
```

then I call the new function use follwing code

```
it('Call new function', function(){
    let email = cy.subValues(15, 8);
    cy.get('#Email').type(email);   
});
```

but the result instead "7" the result is "[object Object]".
[image]

what things I did wrong, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the value from subject, please resolve it as below

```
cy.subValues(15, 8).then(x => cy.get('#Email').type(x));
```

Comment: is that possible assign the value from "cy.subValues(15, 8)" to vriable "email"

Comment: Refer to [link](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values), we could hardly assign or work with the return values of any Cypress command because it runs asynchronously. 
However, a possible but slightly different way could be:
`let y = cy.subValues(15, 8); y.then(val => console.log('y resolved to:', val)); `